# No Access to Knowledge Article Detail Tab as System Administrator Profile Sandbox

Tags: knowledge

No Access to Knowledge Article Detail Tab as System Administrator Profile Sandbox
I Have gone through everything I can think of to give access.

- Profile access
- Permission Set Access
- OWD
- Knowledge Settings/licensing
- record type and page layout assignment, etc.
- Logged in as the user that created the Articles
- Data Categories

Steps -

1. Go to Knowledge Tab
2. See List of Articles
3. Go to a article Record
4. Details Tab - "You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary."
5. I can see the related list(added Files just to check)
6. I can see the Versions related list(tab)

I can **not** see the Publish, Edit, and Edit as Draft buttons.(available and visible by looking at page layout)

I can create a new article and see the details and buttons.

I'm not sure where else to check what could be preventing me to see and edit the articles.
They are visible in Production

Comment: Is this a partial sandbox? I've had issues of data corruption that caused a similar behavior and needed a salesforce support case to fix it.

Comment: Yes it is, that must be the problem. I dont know what else it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely an issue with partial sandbox refreshes. I've had this occur the last two times I refreshed my partial sandbox (specifically this knowledge permission issue) and needed support cases to clear it up.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000017wpcQAA

That known issue correlates to what I'm saying although it says it is "fixed". I presume the issue related to partial is that only some data is copied and it's possible a required related piece is not carried over (file attached to article, etc).